# What is the scope of event notification subscriptions?

Tags: advantage-database-server

In advantage, when I subscribe to an event (via `sp_CreateEvent`) at what level is that event created? Per connection?  Per Client?  Database wide?

The application is that I have a long running application where occasionally ads connections are reset due to errors.  Do I need to recreate (`sp_CreateEvent`) in addition to resubscribe (`sp_WaitForEvent`) when creating new connections?

Also, is there a way to check if a certain event already exists for my given connection/application/whatever level events exist at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are created on a per database level, however any connection that wishes to wait on an event must create the event using `sp_CreateEvent`.  Think of it more like `sp_CreateEvent` *registers* a connection for an event as opposed to *creating* it.

All connections must create/register for the event if they wish to wait on it, so if a connection dies due to an error and is re-created it must again call `sp_CreateEvent` and `sp_WaitForEvent`.

There is no way to simply check if an event exists.  Probably the best way to check is to call `sp_WaitForEvent` and check for an error.  Specify 0 for the timeout if you want it to return right away.  You could also call `sp_CreateEvent` or `sp_DropEvent` and check for errors, but you might have unintended consequences if the event exists or not.

Read more about [events](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_events_notifications_.htm) in our online documentation.